# java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using pass word: YES)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm so grateful for the guys who have assisted me with advice on my previous post of the program below. This is my first sql-java (database) program, though I have some basic college knowledge of the two languages. I set my CLASSPATH via environment variable as per advice and YES the FirstExample.java / FirstExample.class is successfully compiled by Java Compiler and recognized at run time of the the JVM in the command line unlike before.
But then while trying to connect to the database I receive a long error message that I can't understand. 
**I'm a bit suspicious this could bit arising from 'username' issue, though I'm not really sure as I'm a newbie with database programing.

I'm wondering neither in the MySQL configuration wizard nor SQL -database design does 'username' appear though it's part of my tutorial FirstExample.java.**

Please assist with solving this problem giving me head ache the whole day, thanks in advance.

Below is the command line error message:

```
 Connecting to database...
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using pass
word: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4736)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1342)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2
526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java
:347)    
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at FirstExample.main(FirstExample.java:22)  
Goodbye!
```

Below is the basic information:
**I saved the file as:** `C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib\FirstExample.java`  then compiled to `FirstExample.class`

**CLASSPATH:** `C:\glassfish3\jdk\jre\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector J\mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.ja`r

**CATALINA:** `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar`

**JAVA_HOME:** `C:\glassfish3\jdk`

**path:** `C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin`

**MySQL directory:** `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5`.

Here is the database info:

```
database - 'EMP'.  
table -  'Employees'.     
password - 'password'   
Columns; id; age; first; last.  
data;   100; 28; Zaid; Khann.
```

Java program:

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages    
import java.sql.*; // for standard JDBC programs    

public class FirstExample {  
    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

// Database credentials
static final String USER = "username";
static final String PASS = "password";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        Class.forName ( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

        //STEP 4: Execute a query
        System.out.println("Creating Statement...");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        //STEP 5: Extract from result set
        while(rs.next()){
            //Retrieve by column name
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            int age = rs.getInt("age");
            String first = rs.getString("first");
            String last = rs.getString("last");

            //Display values
            System.out.print("ID: " + id);
            System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
            System.out.print(", First: " + first);
            System.out.print(", Last: " + last);

        }
        //STEP 6: Clean-up enviroment
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        //Handle errors for JDBC
        se.printStackTrace();   
    }catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle errors for Class.forName
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        //finally block used to close resources
        try{
            if (stmt !=null)
            stmt.close();
        } catch(SQLException se2) {

        }// nothing we can do
        try{
            if(conn !=null)
                conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }//end finally try
        }//end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
}//end main  
}//end FirstExample
```

This is line 22 of the Java program in code editor:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
```

Comment: check your mysql username and password if it is correct or not

Comment: Your mysql username and password are not correct. I think the error message "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'" is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: You can test whether or not the username/password is correct by typing `mysql -uusername -ppassword` in the command line.

Comment: Thanx all guys, it worked right this time, I used USER = "root"

Answer (score 1):

Check your username and password, you are using *username* as username and *password* as password, I think that your password is correct (because your database info said so), so you can try to change username to root:

static final String USER = "root";

Comment: This work for me. I use `sa` as username when I should have been using `root` instead for mySQL. Thank you. Chenqui.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `username` as username,  `password` as password and you are logging in from `localhost`. You have to have an entry in the `mysql.user` table that corresponds to this.

Use `CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'` to create the user you are logging in with.